# Hide all red cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide all RED cells within a worksheet by pressing on a command button. How can I do this by using a Macro? I also want another button to unhide them. Currently I have the following which isn't working:

```
Sub HideRow()    
Dim i As Long    
Dim LASTROW As Long    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LASTROW = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LASTROW    
    If Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then    
        Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True    
    End If    
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. We help with #3. #1-2 are entirely YOUR responsibility.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I had come up with the following, but it isn't working:

Sub HideRow()

Dim i As Long

Dim LASTROW As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LASTROW = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LASTROW
If Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next 'i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Comment: Please put it in the Original Post Using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38599167/edit)

Comment: Should probably add Excel-VBA tag since I do not believe excel formulas can detect anything to do with colours.

Comment: How is the cell colored?  Is it through Conditional Formatting?

Comment: No, they are coloured manually by people.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so on which line?

Comment: Just tested and the code as is works for me.  could your users be using the wrong "red" fill?

Comment: You could use: lastused = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

Comment: you wrote: "Currently I have the following which isn't working:"  You need to be more specific at what is not working, be descriptive and detailed as all our crystal balls are in the shop getting fixed.........

Comment: you can use autofilter to filter cells are not red color

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure LASTROW is valid, Maybe you mess up columns?

You search last row by `Cells(Rows.Count, 2)`, 2 means column B.
But you check color in column C  `Range("C" & i)`
BTW you could just use `Cells(i,3)` instead of `Range("C" & i)`